# Как заменить русское слово в переменной, на слово сочетаемое на английской раскладке клавиатуры PHP

Tags: php

Допустим есть динамическая переменная:

```
$words = "слово"
```

куда записываются слова из словаря.
Как можно сделать так чтобы эти буквы в переменной менялись на английские т.е:
привет - ghbdtn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создать массив соответствия символов, заменить.

```
$oldWord = 'абв';

$symbols = [
  'а' => 'f',
  'б' => ',',
  'в' => 'd',
  ...
];

$newWord = strtr($oldWord, $symbols);
```

Comment: это конечно тоже подойдет, но, чистой воды извращенность. По канонам и правильно было бы использовать PHP библиотеки по определению и перевода/замены букв...

Comment: есть же для подобного поиска с последующей заменой функция : `strtr($oldWord, $symbols);`

Comment: @user2736875 , много под что есть библиотеки и фреймворки

Comment: @Эдуард , действительно. Исправил